# Inserting jsoup Elements into Mysql with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, jsoup

I want to extract some Elements from a webpage and insert them into MySQL database using JDBC.

The extracted Elements don't be inserted in the DB!

Firstly I used this code and tested the output with System.out.println(//Extracted Elements );

no probem in output.

```
 try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/all-prices").get(); 

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        String sql  =null;
        conn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://Localhost:3306/test?" +"user=root&password=mypassword");
        for(Element ele :doc.select("table").select("tr.TPriceBody") )
    { 
        System.out.println( ""+ele.select("td.PTPrice").text().replace(" ر.س","") +" \t" +ele.select("td.PTmodel").text()+" \t"+ele.select("td.PTmodel a").attr("abs:HREF"));

     sql =" insert into data"
                +"(Type_ID,Price,Site_Comment,Buy_Link)"
                +"values" 
                + "('" + 1   + "',"
                + "('" + ele.select("td.PTPrice").text().replace(" ر.س","") + "',"
                + "('" + ele.select("td.PTmodel a").attr("abs:HREF") + "')";
        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();           
             }
    catch(Exception e)
              {} 
                }
```

This the output

```
        30,000 ر.س  
35,000  هيونداي I10 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/hyundai
35,000  بروتون ساجا 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/proton
36,000  هيونداي I10 2015    
38,000  ميتسوبيشي ميراج 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/mitsubishi
38,000  هيونداي جراند i10 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/hyundai/grand-i10/year/2015
    40,000 ر.س  
40,000  شيفروليه سبارك 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/chevrolet
40,650  سوزوكى سويفت 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/suzuki
41,500  سوزوكى سويفت ديزاير 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/suzuki/swift-dzire/year/2015
42,000  نيسان ميكرا 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/nissan
43,900  سوزوكى سويفت ديزاير 2015    
43,900  هيونداي اكسنت 2015  
44,000  هيونداي I20 2015    
44,000  هيونداي اكسنت 2015  
44,000  كيا ريو 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/kia/rio/year/2015
45,000  كيا ريو 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/kia
45,000  كيا بيكانتو 2015    
46,000  شيفروليه سبارك 2015     
47,000  مازدا مازدا 2 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/mazda
47,000  ام جى 3 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/moris-garage/mg-3/year/2015
47,000  بروتون جين 2 2015   
47,000  بروتون بيرسونا 2015     
47,000  نيسان ميكرا 2015    
47,000  نيسان صنى 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/nissan/sunny/year/2015
47,500  تويوتا ياريس 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/toyota/yaris/year/2015
48,000  هيونداي I20 2015    
49,000  شيفروليه افيو 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/chevrolet/aveo/year/2015
49,500  ميتسوبيشي اتراج 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/mitsubishi/attrage/year/2015
    50,000 ر.س  
50,000  نيسان صنى 2015  
50,000  كيا سيراتو 2015     
51,000  رينو فلوانس 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/renault/fluence/year/2015
51,000  ام جى 350 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/moris-garage/mg-350/year/2015
51,000  هيونداي ألنترا 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/hyundai/elantra/year/2015
51,000  رينو داستر 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/renault/duster/year/2015
51,000  هوندا جاز 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/honda
51,500  ميتسوبيشي اتراج 2015    
51,900  تويوتا ياريس 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/toyota
52,000  مازدا مازدا 2 2015  
53,000  كيا سول 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/kia/soul/year/2015
53,000  شيفروليه سونك 2015  
53,000  نيسان ميكرا 2015    
53,500  جى ام سى جيمى 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/gmc
53,900  تويوتا ياريس 2015   
54,000  هيونداي ألنترا 2015     
54,000  اسبيرانزا تيجو 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/speranza/tiggo/year/2015
54,000  هيونداي I30 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/hyundai/i30/year/2015
54,000  سيتروين سى اليس 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/citroen
54,000  تويوتا افانزا 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/toyota/avanza/year/2015
54,900  تويوتا ياريس 2015   
55,000  سكودا فابيا 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/skoda
55,000  هيونداي اكسنت 2015  
55,000  هوندا سيتى 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/honda/city/year/2015
55,000  كيا ريو 2015    
55,000  نيسان تيدا 2015     
55,900  تويوتا ياريس 2015   
56,000  بيجو 301 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/peugeot
56,000  كيا ريو 2015    
56,000  اوبل كورسا 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/opel
56,000  نيسان صنى 2015  
56,000  جاك J6 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/jac
57,000  سيتروين سى اليس 2015    
58,000  ام جى 350 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/moris-garage
59,000  بيجو 208 2015   
59,000  ام جى 5 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/moris-garage/mg-5/year/2015
59,000  هوندا سيتى 2015     
59,000  فولكس فاغن بولو 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/volks-wagen
59,000  امجيراند EC 8 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/emgrand
60,000  رينو كابتور 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/renault
60,000  هيونداي I30 2015    
60,000  رينو ميجان 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/renault/megane/year/2015
61,000  رينو داستر 2015     
61,000  بيجو 301 2015   
61,000  نيسان تيدا 2015     
61,000  مرسيدس E Class 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/mercedes
61,000  شيفروليه سونك 2015  
61,750  تويوتا كورولا 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/toyota/corolla/year/2015
62,000  نيسان سنترا 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/nissan/sentra/year/2015
62,900  سوزوكى Sx 4 2015    
63,000  بيجو 308 2015   
63,000  نيسان جوك 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/nissan/juke/year/2015
63,000  ام جى 5 2015    
63,000  رينو ميجان 2015     
63,000  ميتسوبيشي لانسر 2015    
63,000  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
64,750  تويوتا كورولا 2015  
65,000  بيجو 208 2015   
65,000  رينو كابتور 2015    
65,000  مازدا مازدا 3 2015  
65,000  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
65,000  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
65,000  مازدا مازدا 3 2015  
66,000  هوندا سيتى 2015     
66,000  نيسان سنترا 2015    
66,000  نيسان تيدا 2015     
66,000  فولكس فاغن بولو 2015    
67,000  كيا كارينز 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/kia/carens/year/2015
67,000  فورد فيستا 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/ford
67,000  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
67,000  شيفروليه كروز 2015  
67,000  نيسان سنترا 2015    
68,000  رينو سافران 2015    
68,000  رينو فلوانس 2015    
68,000  هيونداي سوناتا 2015     
69,900  هوندا سيفك 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/honda/civic/year/2015
70,000  هوندا HRV 2015  
70,000  كيا كارينز 2015     
70,000  بيجو 308 2015   
70,000  هيونداي فيلوستر 2015    
70,000  بيجو 208 2015   
70,000  رينو كابتور 2015    
70,500  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
71,000  بيجو 408 2015   
71,000  كيا سيراتو 2015     
71,000  فورد فوكس 2015  
71,900  هوندا سيفك 2015     
72,000  كيا سبورتاج 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/kia/sportage/year/2015
72,000  كيا سيراتو 2015     
72,000  نيسان سنترا 2015    
72,000  فورد فيستا 2015     
72,000  كيا سول 2015    
72,000  فورد فوكس 2015  
72,000  هيونداي توسان 2015  
73,000  كيا كارينز 2015     
73,000  نيسان جوك 2015  
73,000  تويوتا هايلكس 2015  
73,000  بيجو 2008 2015  
73,900  هيونداي سوناتا 2015     
74,000  ميتسوبيشي ASX 2015  
74,000  سيتروين C3 2015     
74,000  سيتروين C4 2015     
74,000  سوبارو امبريزا 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/subaru
74,000  هيونداي ألنترا 2015     
    75,000 ر.س  
75,000  فولكس فاغن جيتا 2015    
75,000  هيونداي كوبية 2015  
75,000  هيونداي I40 2015    
75,000  بيجو 308 2015   
76,000  نيسان سنترا 2015    
76,000  كيا كادنزا 2015     
76,000  شيفروليه كروز 2015  
76,000  ميتسوبيشي لانسر 2015    
77,000  ام جى 3 2015    
77,000  سوزوكى فيتارا 2015  
77,000  نيسان تيدا 2015     
77,000  كيا سبورتاج 2015    
77,000  سكودا اوكتافيا 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/skoda/octavia/year/2015
77,000  بيجو 408 2015   
77,000  نيسان جوك 2015  
77,000  هيونداي سوناتا 2015     
77,000  فورد فوكس 2015  
77,500  تويوتا كامري 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/toyota/camry/year/2015
77,900  تويوتا كورولا 2015  
78,000  هيونداي توسان 2015  
78,000  ام جى 6 2015    
78,000  مازدا مازدا 6 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/mazda/mazda-6/year/2015
79,000  شيفروليه كروز 2015  
79,000  هيونداي فيلوستر 2015    
80,000  ميتسوبيشي ASX 2015  
80,000  كيا سيراتو 2015     
80,000  نيسان التيما 2015   
80,000  هيونداي توسان 2015  
81,000  بيجو 2008 2015  
81,000  سوبارو امبريزا 2015     
81,000  تويوتا كامري 2015   
81,000  ميتسوبيشي لانسر 2015    
82,000  جيب كومباس 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/jeep
82,000  كيا كارينز 2015     
82,000  سكودا فابيا 2015    
82,000  سيتروين دى اس 3 2015    
82,000  شيفروليه ماليبو 2015    
82,000  فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
82,000  فورد فيستا 2015     
82,000  كيا سيراتو 2015     
82,000  كيا سورينتو 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/kia/sorento/year/2015
82,900  هيونداي أزيرا 2015  
83,000  بيجو 508 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/peugeot/508/year/2015
83,400  تويوتا راف فور 2015     
83,500  تويوتا انوفا 2015   
84,000  نيسان اكس تريل 2015     
84,000  سوزوكى كيزاشى 2015  
84,000  فولكس فاغن جيتا 2015    
85,000  تويوتا كامري 2015   
85,000  شيفروليه ماليبو 2015    
85,000  كرايسلر 200 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/chrysler
86,000  نيسان سنترا 2015    
86,000  فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
86,000  ميتسوبيشي اوت لاندر 2015    
86,000  تويوتا انوفا 2015   
86,500  هوندا سيفك 2015     
87,000  اوبل أسترا 2015     
87,000  نيسان التيما 2015   
87,000  فورد فوكس 2015  
87,000  سكودا اوكتافيا 2015     
88,000  سوبارو فورستر 2015  
88,000  ام جى 3 2015    
89,000  سكودا ياتى 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/skoda/yeti/year/2015
89,000  فولكس فاغن باسات 2015   
90,000  ام جى 750 2015  
90,000  اوبل كورسا 2015     
90,000  ام جى 3 2015    
90,000  هيونداي I40 2015    
90,000  بيجو 3008 2015  
90,000  مازدا CX 5 2015     
91,000  فورد اسكيب 2015     
91,000  فورد فيوجن 2015     
91,400  تويوتا راف فور 2015     
92,000  هوندا CRV 2015  
92,000  جيب كومباس 2015     
93,000  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
93,000  اوبل أسترا 2015     
93,000  هيونداي سوناتا 2015     
93,000  اودي A1 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/audi
93,500  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
93,500  هوندا أكورد 2015    
94,000  بيجو 3008 2015  
94,000  شيفروليه كابتيفا 2015   
95,000  تويوتا كامري 2015   
95,000  ميتسوبيشي باجيرو 2015   
95,000  بيجو 5008 2015  
96,000  كيا موهافى 2015     
96,000  فولكس فاغن جيتا 2015    
96,000  نيسان اكس تريل 2015     
96,000  سوبارو فورستر 2015  
96,000  نيسان التيما 2015   
97,000  نيسان التيما 2015   
97,000  فولكس فاغن باسات 2015   
97,000  سكودا اوكتافيا 2015     
97,000  اوبل أسترا 2015     
97,000  هيونداي سانتافى 2015    
97,400  تويوتا راف فور 2015     
99,000  رينو اوبتيما 2015   
99,000  هوندا CRV 2015  
99,900  هيونداي جراند سنتافي 2015   
    100,000 ر.س     
100,000     هيونداي توسان 2015  
101,000     كيا كارنفال 2015    
101,000     شيفروليه كابتيفا 2015   
101,000     سيتروين Ds4 2015    
101,000     سيتروين دى اس 3 2015    
101,000     سوبارو ليجاسى 2015  
101,000     سيتروين C5 2015     
102,000     تويوتا اوريون 2015  
102,000     شيفروليه ماليبو 2015    
102,000     فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
102,000     فولكس فاغن بيتل 2015    
102,000     مازدا CX-9 2015     
102,000     فورد توروس 2015     
102,000     رينو اوبتيما 2015   
102,000     اودي A3 2015    
102,000     فورد فيوجن 2015     
102,000     هيونداي سانتافى 2015    
103,200     تويوتا فورتشنر 2015     
103,500     تويوتا كامري 2015   
104,000     ميتسوبيشي باجيرو 2015   
104,000     بيجو 5008 2015  
105,000     نيسان ماكسيما 2015  
105,000     نيسان اكستيرا 2015  
106,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
106,000     كيا سبورتاج 2015    
106,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
106,000     اودي A1 2015    
108,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
108,000     فولكس فاغن باسات 2015   
108,000     شيفروليه سيلفرادو 2015  
108,000     فورد ايدج 2015  
109,000     سوبارو BRZ 2015     
109,000     نيسان التيما 2015   
109,500     هوندا CRV 2015  
110,000     هيونداي أزيرا 2015  
110,000     نيسان اكس تريل 2015     
111,900     هوندا أكورد 2015    
112,000     ام جى 6 2015    
112,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
112,000     كرايسلر 200 2015    
112,000     اودي A3 2015    
112,000     شيفروليه امبالا 2015    
112,000     مازدا مازدا 6 2015  
113,000     كيا سورينتو 2015    
113,000     فورد فلكس 2015  
113,000     جيب شيروكي 2015     
113,000     فورد فيوجن 2015     
113,000     سوبارو فورستر 2015  
113,000     كيا كادنزا 2015     
114,000     جى ام سى ترين 2015  
114,500     تويوتا اوريون 2015  
115,000     سوبارو BRZ 2015     
115,000     نيسان اكستيرا 2015  
115,000     انفينيتي جي 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/infiniti
115,000     شيفروليه سيلفرادو 2015  
116,000     شيفروليه ماليبو 2015    
117,000     تويوتا أفالون 2015  
117,000     هوندا CRV 2015  
117,000     فولكس فاغن بيتل 2015    
117,000     مازدا Mx-5 2015     
118,000     سوبارو ليجاسى 2015  
118,000     شيفروليه كابتيفا 2015   
118,000     بي ام دبليو 116 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/bmw
118,000     فورد اسكيب 2015     
118,000     سكودا سويرب 2015    
118,000     كيا سورينتو 2015    
119,000     هيونداي جينيسيس 2015    
119,000     هيونداي أزيرا 2015  
119,000     اودي A4 2015    
120,000     سوبارو BRZ 2015     
120,000     ميتسوبيشي اوت لاندر 2015    
120,000     نيسان التيما 2015   
120,900     تويوتا برادو 2015   
121,000     نيسان اكستيرا 2015  
121,000     فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
122,000     فولكس فاغن CC 2015  
122,000     نيسان مورانو 2015   
122,000     سكودا اوكتافيا 2015     
122,000     شيفروليه امبالا 2015    
123,000     بيجو 508 2015   
123,000     ميتسوبيشي باجيرو 2015   
123,000     سيتروين C5 2015     
123,000     الفا رميو جوليتا 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/alpha-romeo/giulietta/year/2015
123,000     مازدا CX 5 2015     
123,000     اودي A3 2015    
123,000     فورد F-150 2015     
123,000     فولكس فاغن باسات 2015   
124,000     نيسان باثفايندر 2015    
124,000     تويوتا اف جى 2015   
124,000     اودي Q3 2015    
    125,000 ر.س     
125,000     انفينيتي جي 2015    
126,000     فولفو S60 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/volvo
126,000     شيفروليه ترافيرس 2015   
126,400     تويوتا فورتشنر 2015     
127,000     جى ام سى ترين 2015  
127,000     سوبارو ليجاسى 2015  
128,000     سيتروين دى اس 5 2015    
128,000     فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
128,000     جى ام سى ترين 2015  
128,000     فورد اكسبلورر 2015  
128,000     فورد ايدج 2015  
128,000     فورد توروس 2015     
129,500     هوندا أكورد 2015    
130,000     اودي Q3 2015    
130,000     دودج دورانجو 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/dodge
130,400     تويوتا برادو 2015   
130,999     فولكس فاغن بيتل 2015    
132,000     نيسان ماكسيما 2015  
132,000     اوبل أسترا 2015     
132,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
132,000     ميتسوبيشي باجيرو 2015   
133,000     نيسان باثفايندر 2015    
133,000     فولكس فاغن CC 2015  
133,000     جيب شيروكي 2015     
133,000     بي ام دبليو 316 2015    
133,000     هيونداي سانتافى 2015    
133,900     هوندا أكورد 2015    
134,000     اودي A1 2015    
136,000     هوندا بايلوت 2015   
136,000     شيفروليه كمارو 2015     
136,000     فورد موستانج 2015   
136,000     مينى كوبر 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/mini
137,000     كاديلاك ATS 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/cadillac
137,500     هوندا أكورد 2015    
138,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
138,000     جيب رانجلر 2015     
138,000     سيتروين دى اس 5 2015    
139,000     تويوتا أفالون 2015  
139,000     اودي Q3 2015    
139,000     فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
139,000     شيفروليه ترافيرس 2015   
140,000     مينى كوبر 2015  
140,000     مرسيدس A Class 2015     
142,000     فورد اسكيب 2015     
142,000     نيسان Z 2015    
143,000     فورد فلكس 2015  
143,000     الفا رميو جوليتا 2015   http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/alpha-romeo
143,000     شيفروليه سيلفرادو 2015  
143,000     فورد اكسبيديشن 2015     
143,000     اودي A4 2015    
144,900     هوندا اوديسى 2015   
145,000     شيفروليه امبالا 2015    
145,000     كرايسلر 300 2015    
148,000     شيفروليه تاهو 2015  
148,000     جى ام سى اكاديا 2015    
149,000     بيجو ار سى زد 2015  
149,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
149,000     مرسيدس C 180 2015   
149,000     نيسان مورانو 2015   
149,000     مازدا CX-9 2015     
149,000     فولكس فاغن CC 2015  
149,000     تويوتا أفالون 2015  
149,500     تويوتا اف جى 2015   
    150,000 ر.س     
151,000     اودي A3 2015    
152,000     هيونداي جينيسيس 2015    
152,000     هوندا كروستور 2015  
152,900     هوندا بايلوت 2015   
153,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
153,000     جيب شيروكي 2015     
153,000     فورد ايدج 2015  
153,000     لكزس Is 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/lexus
154,000     مرسيدس GLK 2015     
154,500     تويوتا برادو 2015   
155,000     جى ام سى ترين 2015  
155,000     شيفروليه تاهو 2015  
157,000     فورد موستانج 2015   
157,000     شيفروليه تاهو 2015  
157,000     فولفو V60 2015  
158,000     انفينيتي Q70 2015   
158,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015     
158,000     نيسان باثفايندر 2015    
158,000     فولفو S60 2015  
158,000     فولفو S80 2015  
159,000     جيب رانجلر 2015     
159,000     فورد اكسبلورر 2015  
159,000     فورد F-150 2015     
159,000     فورد توروس 2015     
159,000     لكزس Es 2015    
160,000     فولكس فاغن تيجون 2015   
160,000     مرسيدس C 200 2015   
160,000     فولفو XC60 2015     
160,000     دودج دورانجو 2015   
161,000     فولكس فاغن CC 2015  
161,000     شيفروليه سوبربان 2015   
161,000     شيفروليه كمارو 2015     
162,000     فولفو XC60 2015     
164,000     جيب شيروكي 2015     
164,000     بي ام دبليو 320 2015    
164,000     اودي A4 2015    
164,000     بويك رودماستر 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/buick
165,000     مينى مينى كوبر s 2015   
166,000     اوبل انسجينا 2015   
166,000     كاديلاك اس ار اكس 2015  
167,000     تويوتا برادو 2015   
168,000     تويوتا رنر 2015     
168,000     اودي A6 2015    
168,000     انفينيتي QX 2015    
169,000     اودي A5 2015    
169,000     انفينيتي Q50 2015   
169,000     فورد اكسبيديشن 2015     
169,000     شيفروليه سوبربان 2015   
169,000     مينى كانترى مان 2015    
169,900     هوندا بايلوت 2015   
170,000     شيفروليه كابرس 2015     
171,000     نيسان ارمادا 2015   
171,000     شيفروليه ترافيرس 2015   
172,000     كرايسلر 300 2015    
172,000     شيفروليه كابرس 2015     
172,000     شيفروليه كابرس 2015     
173,000     جى ام سى اكاديا 2015    
173,000     جاغوار XF 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/jaguar
173,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
174,000     نيسان باترول 2015   
174,000     اودي Q5 2015    
174,900     هوندا اوديسى 2015   
175,000     مينى مينى كوبر s 2015   
175,000     مرسيدس 220 2015     
175,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
176,000     اوبل كاسكادا 2015   
177,000     جى ام سى سييرا 2015     
178,000     فولكس فاغن طوارق 2015   
178,000     فولفو XC60 2015     
179,000     مرسيدس 220 2015     
179,000     اوبل انسجينا 2015   
179,000     لكزس Es 2015    
179,000     لكزس Is 2015    
179,000     فورد ايدج 2015  
179,000     فورد فلكس 2015  
179,000     بويك رودماستر 2015  
179,000     فولفو S80 2015  
179,000     مينى كانترى مان 2015    
180,000     جى ام سى سييرا 2015     
180,000     مرسيدس C Class 2015     http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/mercedes/c-class/year/2015
180,000     اودي A5 2015    
181,000     مرسيدس C 250 2015   
181,000     اودي A4 2015    
182,000     كاديلاك ATS 2015    
182,000     شيفروليه ترافيرس 2015   
182,000     انفينيتي Q60 2015   
183,000     لكزس Rx 2015    
184,000     نيسان باثفايندر 2015    
184,000     مرسيدس E Class 2015     
184,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
184,000     لكزس Es 2015    
184,000     بي ام دبليو 320 2015    
184,000     بي ام دبليو 328 2015    
184,000     بي ام دبليو Z4 2015     
185,000     نيسان باترول 2015   
185,000     فولكس فاغن طوارق 2015   
186,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
187,000     كاديلاك Cts 2015    
187,000     فورد موستانج 2015   
187,000     مرسيدس SLK Class 2015   
188,000     كرايسلر 300 2015    
188,000     اودي A5 2015    
188,000     دودج تشارجر 2015    
189,000     لكزس Gs 2015    
189,000     هيونداي جينيسيس 2015    
189,000     نيسان ارمادا 2015   
189,000     فولكس فاغن جولف 2015    
189,000     فورد اكسبلورر 2015  
190,000     شيفروليه سوبربان 2015   
190,000     كيا كورس 2015   
190,000     فولفو S60 2015  
191,000     مرسيدس C 250 2015   
191,250     تويوتا لاند كروزر 2015  
193,000     انفينيتي Q50 2015   
194,000     فورد توروس 2015     
194,000     شيفروليه كمارو 2015     
194,000     جى ام سى سييرا 2015     
194,000     لكزس Is 2015    
195,000     جى ام سى يوكون 2015     
195,000     فولفو S60 2015  
196,000     كاديلاك ATS 2015    
196,000     جى ام سى اكاديا 2015    
196,900     بورش بوكستر 2015    http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/porsche
197,000     اودي A6 2015    
197,000     فورد موستانج 2015   
197,900     تويوتا سيكويا 2015  
199,000     مرسيدس E 200 2015   
199,000     لكزس Es 2015    
199,000     فولفو XC60 2015     
    200,000 ر.س     
200,000     اودي A5 2015    
200,000     مرسيدس 220 2015     
200,000     بي ام دبليو Z4 2015     
200,000     جى ام سى اكاديا 2015    
200,000     اودي A5 2015    
201,000     مرسيدس GLK 2015     
201,000     مرسيدس E Class 2015     
202,000     شيفروليه تاهو 2015  
203,000     انفينيتي Q70 2015   
203,000     جاغوار XF 2015  
204,000     انفينيتي Q60 2015   
204,000     فولفو XC60 2015     
204,000     لكزس Gs 2015    
204,000     ليفان 520 2015  http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/ar/car/info/lifan
205,000     بي ام دبليو 520 2015    
205,750     تويوتا لاند كروزر 2015  
206,000     دودج تشالنجر 2015   
207,000     مرسيدس SLK Class 2015   
208,000     بي ام دبليو 328 2015    
208,000     شيفروليه سيلفرادو 2015  
209,000     بورش بوكستر اس 2015     
210,000     تويوتا برادو 2015   
210,000     مينى كانترى مان 2015    
210,000     فورد اكسبيديشن 2015     
210,000     بورش كايمان 2015    
211,000     هيونداي جينيسيس 2015    
212,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015     
212,000     مرسيدس E 200 2015   
214,000     انفينيتي Q60 2015   
214,000     فولكس فاغن طوارق 2015   
214,000     جاغوار XF 2015  
214,000     اودي Q5 2015    
214,000     اودي A5 2015    
215,000     لكزس Rx 2015    
215,000     لكزس Is 2015    
219,000     اودي A5 2015    
220,000     كرايسلر 300 2015    
220,000     لكزس Gs 2015    
220,000     فورد اكسبلورر 2015  
220,000     بي ام دبليو 520 2015    
224,000     اودي Q7 2015    
225,000     مرسيدس E Class 2015     
225,000     لكزس Es 2015    
225,000     لكزس Gs 2015    
226,000     مرسيدس C 350 2015   
226,250     تويوتا لاند كروزر 2015  
227,000     بورش كايمان اس 2015     
229,000     شيفروليه سوبربان 2015   
230,000     كرايسلر 300 2015    
230,000     كاديلاك Cts 2015    
230,000     اودي A5 2015    
232,000     بورش بوكستر اس 2015     
233,000     بورش كايمان 2015    
235,000     مرسيدس SLK Class 2015   
235,000     انفينيتي Q60 2015   
235,000     لكزس Is 2015    
235,000     لكزس Rx 2015    
238,000     جى ام سى يوكون 2015     
240,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015     
240,000     مرسيدس E 300 2015   
243,000     مرسيدس CLA Class 2015   
243,000     مرسيدس E Class 2015     
244,000     جاغوار XF 2015  
244,000     اودي A7 2015    
244,000     فولكس فاغن طوارق 2015   
245,000     بي ام دبليو 335 2015    
245,000     اودي A6 2015    
245,000     بي ام دبليو 135 2015    
245,000     اودي A5 2015    
246,000     مرسيدس E 250 2015   
    250,000 ر.س     
250,000     لكزس Rx 2015    
250,000     كاديلاك XTS 2015    
250,000     مرسيدس M Class 2015     
255,000     شيفروليه كمارو 2015     
255,000     اودي Q7 2015    
255,000     فولفو XC90 2015     
261,000     لكزس Gs 2015    
263,000     مرسيدس E 350 2015   
268,000     لكزس Gs 2015    
270,000     بي ام دبليو 528 2015    
270,000     مرسيدس E 300 2015   
271,000     مرسيدس E 400 2015   
272,000     اودي A7 2015    
274,000     مرسيدس E 350 2015   
275,000     جى ام سى يوكون 2015     
275,000     فولكس فاغن طوارق 2015   
276,000     بي ام دبليو 528 2015    
279,000     بورش كيان 2015  
280,000     مرسيدس E 350 2015   
280,000     بي ام دبليو 535 2015    
283,000     مرسيدس E 400 2015   
285,000     كاديلاك XTS 2015    
286,000     جيب جراند شيروكي 2015   
290,000     بورش بوكستر 2015    
295,000     جاغوار ف تيب 2015   
298,000     تويوتا لاند كروزر 2015  
300,000     بي ام دبليو X5 2015     
301,000     شيفروليه كورفيت 2015    
305,000     جاغوار XJ 2015  
308,000     اودي S6 2015    
316,000     جاغوار ف تيب 2015   
316,600     بورش كايين اس 2015  
317,000     بي ام دبليو 535 2015    
317,000     لكزس Ls 2015    
320,000     مرسيدس E 500 2015   
322,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015     
322,000     مرسيدس C AMG 2015   
323,000     مرسيدس CLS Class 2015   
323,000     بورش كيان 2015  
330,000     بورش كايمان اس 2015     
330,000     بورش كيان 2015  
332,000     شيفروليه كورفيت 2015    
332,000     اودي A8 2015    
334,000     مرسيدس E 500 2015   
336,000     جاغوار ف تيب 2015   
337,000     شيفروليه كورفيت 2015    
337,000     الفا رميو 4C 2015   
338,000     مرسيدس M Class 2015     
340,000     بي ام دبليو 550 2015    
345,000     مرسيدس E 500 2015   
346,000     جاغوار XJ 2015  
347,000     كاديلاك اسكاليد 2015    
352,000     بورش 911 2015   
356,000     جاغوار ف تيب 2015   
357,000     لكزس Ls 2015    
357,000     كاديلاك اسكاليد 2015    
363,000     بي ام دبليو 550 2015    
368,000     لكزس Lx 2015    
378,000     لكزس Ls 2015    
380,000     بورش كيان 2015  
388,000     لكزس Ls 2015    
391,000     بورش باناميرا 2015  
392,000     اودي A8 2015    
394,000     لكزس Lx 2015    
395,000     مرسيدس CLS Class 2015   
400,000     بورش كايين اس 2015  
402,000     لكزس Lx 2015    
407,000     جاغوار XF 2015  
408,000     مرسيدس S Class 2015     
410,000     بي ام دبليو M3 2015     
420,000     بي ام دبليو M3 2015     
438,000     جاغوار XJ 2015  
438,000     جاغوار ف تيب 2015   
439,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015     
443,000     بورش 911 2015   
454,000     نيسان جى تى ار 2015     
459,000     لكزس Ls 2015    
469,000     جاغوار ف تيب 2015   
503,000     مرسيدس S Class 2015     
510,000     مرسيدس CLS Class 2015   
525,000     بورش كيان 2015  
536,000     بورش باناميرا 2015  
550,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015     
561,000     اودي A8 2015    
577,000     مرسيدس S Class 2015     
600,000     مرسيدس S Class 2015     
622,000     جاغوار XJ 2015  
689,000     مرسيدس AMG 2015
```

But when I tried to use  stmt.executeUpdate(sql); within for Element loop
the output is only  the first line

```
    for(Element ele :doc.select("table").select("tr.TPriceBody") )
    { 
         System.out.println( ""+ele.select("td.PTPrice").text().replace(" ر.س","") +" \t" +ele.select("td.PTmodel").text()+" \t"+ele.select("td.PTmodel a").attr("abs:HREF"));




         sql =" insert into data"
                +"(Type_ID,Price,Site_Comment,Buy_Link)"
                +"values" 
                + "('" + 1   + "',"
                + "('" + ele.select("td.PTPrice").text().replace(" ر.س","") + "',"
                + "('" + ele.select("td.PTmodel a").attr("abs:HREF") + "')";
          stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    }
```

The output

30,000 ر.س

What is the problem with stmt.executeUpdate(sql); !!!

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes , no problem or no message getted found with debugging

Comment: Well, by debugging I meant, what happens after the first iteration of loop?

Comment: (Debug  as java application )30,000 ر.س  
ٍSame output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a stupid error.
it's in my sql String.

So I have changed it with the following code and it works.

```
sql =" insert into data"
                    +"(Type_ID,price,buy_Link,Site_Comment)"
                    +"values" 
                    + "('" + 1   + "','"


                    +ele.select("td.PTPrice").text().replace(" ر.س","")   +"','"
                    +ele.select("td.PTmodel a").attr("abs:HREF")  +"','"
                    +ele.select("td.PTmodel").text()+
                     "');";
```